# function was not declared in this scope. What am I missing?

Tags: c++

my functions output_all, add_item, and remove_item are all getting this error from the main.cc file. What am I missing? I assumed this was pretty straight forward, but obviously I messed it up. I'll include my files below. Thank you in advance for any help!

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "basket.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){


int choice;
string item;

cout << "Would you like to: \n\n 1.See List \n 2.Add an Item \n 3.Remove an item \n 4.Exit \n\n Please Enter a number: ";
cin >> choice;

if (choice == 1){

output_all(cout);

}

else if (choice == 2){

cout << "Please enter the item you would like to add to the list: ";
cin >> item;
add_item(item);

}

else if (choice == 3){

cout << "Please enter the name of the item you would like to remove: ";
cin >> item;
remove_item(item);
}

else if (choice == 4){

exit(1);

}


else {

main();

}



return (0);

}
```

basket.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class basket{

public:
    //function will output all of the items currently in the list
    void output_all(ostream& fout);

    //Function will allow user to add item to list
    void add_item(const string& item);

    //function will remove item from list after checking that item exists in the list
    void remove_item(const string& item);

    // accessor  method to access the string name
    string get_name();


private:

//string variable used for storing thr list
string name;

};
```

basket.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "basket.h"
using namespace std;



void basket::output_all(ostream& fout){

fout << name;



}


void basket::add_item(const string& item){

name = name + " " + item;


}


void basket::remove_item(const string& item){

int num = name.find(item);

name.erase(num, item.length());
}


string basket::get_name(){

return (name);


}
```

Comment: Your functions are methods in a class (and are not static) so you need to make an instance of that class and call the methods. They're not free functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are calling functions like `output_all`, `add_item`, `remove_item` in your `main`. There's no such functions in your program. Hence the [obvious] error.

If you tried to call member functions of class `basket`, then you should have declared an object of type `basket` and used a completely different syntax (member access syntax). Your favorite C++ book will have plenty of explanations and examples of this.

BTW, it is illegal to manually call `main` function in C++. You have to learn to use cycles to achieve what you are trying to do with that recursive call to `main`.

Comment: Why is the call to main call illegal? Would I use a while loop instead?

Comment: ahh... and also as an aside, now that my program will run, do you have any Idea why "name" will no keep it's values? When I try the output_all fucntion, "name" is always empty. I added lines of code to output the list after anything was removed or added, and every time there is only one word in name after adding a new object, and when I try to remove something, there is nothing to remove! Thank you!

Comment: @user2905256: It is illegal becuase language specification says it is illegal. `main` is special. For one example, it might confail hidden prologue and epilogue code, which cannot be meaningfully executed more than once.

Comment: @user2905256: And I don't know whay your `name` is always empty. It is not possible to say what's wrong without seeing the actual real code.

Answer (score 0):

I can see `output_all()`, `add_item()`, `remove_item()` are non static member of `basket` class. So `output_all(cout)` should be called from an object like: `basketObj.output_all(cout);`